# Wrong remote file identifier specified: wrong string length

Tags: python

How can this problem be solved and what is it? I have already tried all the options, checked all the variables, checked the entire database and don't know what to do?

```
import sqlite3 as sq
from create_bot import bot , dp

def sql_start():
    global base , cur
    base = sq.connect('happy_birthdays.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base connected OK!')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS birthdays(day TEXT, month PRIMARY KEY , 
    year TEXT ,fullName TEXT)')
    base.commit()

async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO birthdays VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()

async def sql_read(message):
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM birthdays').fetchall():
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0]+ret[1]+ret[2]+ret[-1])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3eLF.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're doing there but after some short googling it looks that this is part of a telegram bot. It seems that at least one of the parameters of the call to `bot.send_photo` is wrong.

Comment: @Matthias Yes , I 'm making a bot in python and my problem is that all the parameters are specified correctly , I have text everywhere .Can you please help me personally, or if it's not difficult for you to contact me?